# SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW option greyed out (not changeable)

Tags: android, permissions, system-alert-window

I'm working on an App that is uses the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. I've added the permission to the Manifest.

In my activity, I've added the following code to ask permission at runtime.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 5469);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 5469: {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But, as the "Draw over other Apps" setting page is opened, the 'switch button' to allow the permission is greyed out(not clickable).

Given below is the screenshot :

[image]

Code for Manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.graphics.unlockbrtest">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="Settings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".UnlockReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".FloatingActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

</application>
```

What am I doing wrong that the option is greyed out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and post your manifest.

Comment: Added Manifest!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `<uses-permission>` element to be an immediate child of `<manifest>`, outside of the `<application>` element.

Comment: Works! Thank you soo much!